# How to use an array from another class Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance

having a bit of a dilemma here. My method GetData() stores an array in jsondata1. How would I use that array in another class? I already set it as a subclass of Data. Thanks!

```
class Data {

    let parameters = ["test": ViewController().myinfo]


    func GetData() {  
        AF.request("my url", parameters: parameters).responseDecodable(of: Array<JsonData>.self ) { (response) in
            let jsondata1 = response.value
            // debugPrint(response)
            print(jsondata1)
        }
    }
}



class Testing : Data {

    func AnnualTesting() {
    
        //How would I reference jsondata1 here?
        debugPrint(jsondata1)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not "storing" the data at all. You are printing it and throwing it away.

Comment: Before working with json and asynchronous calls like `AF.request` here I think you need to learn the basics about classes and structs first and how to initiate them and pass data between objects and so on. This question has so many issues so it is in my opinion too broad to be meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

Your declaration of jsondata1 is in scope of some block.
It is not visible from outside.

You have to declare it in interface of class,
just like you did with variable "parameters".

In general you can access variable from another class if it's declared in interface. It can be declared as instance variable or static (class) variable. And you should have instance of class to access instance var and should not have instance to access class / static variable.

Or as you did, via inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

A few things...see comments.

```
class Data {

    // This kind of thing is the source of more bugs than I can count.
    // Are you *sure* you want to create a brand new ViewController that's connected to nothing?
    let parameters = ["test": ViewController().myinfo]

    // Declare an instance variable so it's visible to the subclass
    // (Not sure what data type you want to use here.  I'm calling it a String for convenience.)
    var jsondata1: String?  

    func GetData() {
        AF.request("my url", parameters: parameters).responseDecodable(of: Array<JsonData>.self ) { (response) in

            // Note that this is filled in asynchronously,
            // so isn't available as soon as the function is called.
            // Currently you have no way of knowing in other code when the result *is* available.
            self.jsondata1 = response.value

           // debugPrint(response)
            print(jsondata1)
        }
    }

}

class Testing : Data {

    func AnnualTesting() {
        
        //How would I reference jsondata1 here?
        debugPrint(jsondata1 ?? "Nothing to see here")
    }

}
```